# ActiveAdmin -- Show list of checkboxes for nested form instead of a form to add items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have a nested form `categories` for `stores` resource. They have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

**When I create the nested form, I get the following on the stores form:**

[image]

**But what I really want is a checklist like this:**

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out that after creating those relationships between the models, I don't need to do the `f.has_many` loop in the activeadmin resource. Instead, I just needed the following to make it work:

```
f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes
```

This will automatically take the categories and check the default ones (and also handle any changes made to it).

Comment: You may need to add `:category_ids` to `attr_accesible` on the model.

Comment: All this might be handled differently now in Rails 4

Comment: In Rails 4 needs to include `permit_params category_ids: []` in ActiveAdmin resource.

Comment: its taking name as default to display as checkbox ,but I want to diplay another field name instead name how can I do this ?

If I go by adding collection option there .. on edit again I need to do code to automatically selects the saved ones.

Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed by using member_label option in formtastic

Comment: Too add on to @Umesh: you will have to do both permit_params in the ActiveAdmin resource AND the corresponding controller.